# How to connect mobile application with website database (mysql google cloud)

Tags: android, mysql, mobile

I want to develop a mobile application (android app) for my company web application. So , it will use the same database with the web database. My company use mysql google cloud. How can i connect my mobile application with the database ?

Comment: By creating a web based api that can access the database and in turn is accessible from any mobile device through the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Actually ran into the same scenario recently. What i did was went ahead and looked into how to specifically connect your android application to phpmyadmin, which is a database that can connect android to your web sites database. Not sure who your web host is but i have a site that is hosted by Hostgator and they implement phpmyadmin in order for the webmaster to go ahead and handle the database. For more info i have posted this link which will guide you on the proper steps to take to connect phpmyadmin to your android application.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0_XE0UFeWvaY5NeFcFaGmEFJmJGhnims

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Im a newbie in this area, so i am not really understand how things work but sure i will learn anything related to it. So much thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create api interface in backend (php, etc...) through web to access database.
Use httpconnection to connect web interface and upload/download data by parameters.

Comment: Thank you for the help . :)